# how to use stl map for more than one fields without nesting another map in it

Tags: stl, dictionary

i have to use stl map containing 3 values : float(key) , int ,int.
For the last two ints without using another map , how can i declare my map and insert values in it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `struct data_type { int x; int y; };`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
struct foo
{
    int x;
    int y;
};

...

std::map<float,foo> myMap;

...

foo a = { 5, 2 };
myMap[3.2] = a;
```